# Map (/@) behavior

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I guess this <s>is something easy that I'm overlooking</s> is a clear sign of illiteracy, but anyway.

How is that

```
(Map[Sign, LessEqual[x, y]]) === LessEqual[Sign[x], Sign[y]]
-> True
```

But

```
(Map[Sign, LessEqual[-1, -100]]) == LessEqual[Sign[-1], Sign[-100]]
-> False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Trace on the lhs will help to show what has happened.

```
Trace[Map[Sign, LessEqual[-1, -100]]]
```

Out[2]= {{-1 <= -100, False}, Sign /@ False, False}

Notice that Map has no HoldXXX attributes.

```
Attributes[Map]
```

Out[3]= {Protected}

So the LessEqual evaluates before Map does anything. At which point you get

```
Map[Sign,False]
```

As False is an atomic expression, this just evaluates to False.

The rhs of course evaluates to True, since Sign[-1] and Sign[-100] are both -1.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: Thanks! I almost always used Map with a List head, so never cared/realized about that.

Answer (score 3):

Look what happens when you do it in two steps:

```
In[1]:= LessEqual[-1,-100]
Out[1]= False

In[2]:= Map[Sign, False]
Out[2]= False
```

The second result there may be surprising, but it happens to be how the `Map` function works; if you use `Map` on an expression with length 0 (like the symbol `False`), it just returns that expression unchanged. Another example:

```
In[3]:= Map[f, "Pillsy"]
Out[3]= "Pillsy"
```

On the other hand, obviously

```
In[4]:= LessEqual[Sign[-1],Sign[-100]]
Out[4]= True
```

Comment: Thanks! You should not Map yourself!

Comment: @belisarius It's fine to Map yourself, if you don't mind suffering from idempotence.